# OAuth with Twitter script in Python is not working

Tags: python, oauth, twitter

I'm writing a script of OAuth in Python.

For testing this, I use Twitter API. But it is not working well.

```
def test():
    params = {
            "oauth_consumer_key": TWITTER_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,
            "oauth_nonce": "".join(random.choice(string.digits + string.letters) for i in xrange(7)),
            "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA1",
            "oauth_timestamp": str(int(time.time())),
            "oauth_token": res_dict["oauth_token"],
            "oauth_version": "1.0",
            }
    status = {"status": u"Always_look_on_the_bright_side_of_life".encode("UTF-8")}
    print status
    params.update(status)
    url = "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml"
    key = "&".join([TWITTER_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, res_dict["oauth_token_secret"]])
    msg = "&".join(["POST", urllib.quote(url,""),
                    urllib.quote("&".join([k+"="+params[k] for k in sorted(params)]), "-._~")])
    print msg
    signature = hmac.new(key, msg, hashlib.sha1).digest().encode("base64").strip()
    params["oauth_signature"] = signature
    req = urllib2.Request(url,
          headers={"Authorization":"OAuth", "Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    req.add_data("&".join([k+"="+urllib.quote(params[k], "-._~") for k in params]))
    print req.get_data()
    res = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    print res
```

This script (status="Always_look_on_the_bright_side_of_life") is working.

But, in case status is "Always look on the bright side of life"(replaced underscore with space), it isn't working(is returning HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized).

I referenced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688766/getting-401-on-twitter-oauth-post-requests/2165600), but failed.

Please give me some advice. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for using appropriate sample strings in a Python example.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem in OAuth with FaceBook a while ago. The problem is that the signature validation on server side fails. See your signature generation code here:

```
msg = "&".join(["POST", urllib.quote(url,""),
                urllib.quote("&".join([k+"="+params[k] for k in sorted(params)]), "-._~")])
print msg
signature = hmac.new(key, msg, hashlib.sha1).digest().encode("base64").strip()
```

It uses the raw (non-encoded) form of the string to generate the signature. However, the server side generates validates the signature against the URL quoted string:

```
req.add_data("&".join([k+"="+urllib.quote(params[k], "-._~") for k in params]))
```

To fix the code, you need to do fix this line by creating the signature from the url encoded parameter:

```
msg = "&".join(["POST", urllib.quote(url,""),
                urllib.quote("&".join([k+"="+urllib.quote(params[k], "-._~") for k in sorted(params)]), "-._~")])
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is to add `status = urllib.quote(status)` after `status = {"status": u"Always_look_on_the_bright_side_of_life".encode("UTF-8")}`. This will escape the spaces and other special characters as required.